# Как написать этот запрос на mssql

Tags: sql-server

У меня на табле есть такие данные

```
Date       - число 
01.07.2020 - 1
02.07.2020 - 1
05.07.2020 - 2
06.07.2020 - 2
07.07.2020 - 2
10.07.2020 - 1
11.07.2020 - 1
14.07.2020 - 3
17.07.2020 - 1
18.07.2020 - 1
19.07.2020 - 1
23.07.2020 - 1
24.07.2020 - 1
```

Какой select должен быть что на результате вила такая

```
01.07.2020 - старт 02.07.2020 - энд
05.07.2020 - старт 07.07.2020 - энд
10.07.2020 - старт 11.07.2020 - энд
14.07.2020 - старт 14.07.2020 - энд
17.07.2020 - старт 24.07.2020 - энд
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, описание к задаче. Какие данные хранятся в БД, что такое 1, 2, 3 в таблице? Как определяется start/end дата? 
И кстати, где ваше решение?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS (SELECT dt,
               num,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) rn1,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY dt) rn2
        FROM test)
SELECT DISTINCT
       MIN(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY rn1 - rn2) start,
       MAX(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY rn1 - rn2) finish
FROM cte
ORDER BY start;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=aba3117eaaca4b2cdfa9e8b97c8b7f20)

Comment: Хороший ответ. +1 с моей стороны.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Так это же самый что ни на есть стандартный gaps and islands...

Comment: стандартный gaps and islands... Я знаю это. Я обычно использую другой подход, используя функцию LAG ().